# Pandas output the average value of 2 month data per 10 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i'm really new at python and i have a problem with this situation.
i have a dataset just like this

```
Client   Date                 Respuesta        SucursalId    OperationId  Cantidad
  a     2018-02-07 08:21:01   Autorizado          0115           01         1
  a     2018-02-07 08:22:05   Autorizado          0115           01         1
  a     2018-02-07 08:31:07   No Autorizado       0210           10         1
  a     2018-02-07 08:34:55   No Autorizado       0210           10         1
```

then i need to set index

```
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]))
```

then i need to group the transactions by 10 Minutes but i need to keep 3 Columns (Respuesta, OperationId, SucursalId)

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="10Min")).apply(lambda x:x.groupby(["Respuesta","OperationId","SucursalId"]).sum())
```

i got this result (pretty much what i need)

```
Date                  Respuesta      SucursalId   OperationId    Cantidad
2018-02-07 08:20:00    Autorizado        0115          01           2
2018-02-07 08:30:00    No Autorizado     0210          10           2
```

the thing is that i have this information for like 2 month, i append new one every day and i need to create an average base of just 10 min freq like

```
Date         Respuesta       SucursalId     OperationId   Mean              
08:20:00     Autorizado         0115           01           1.5 (mean of every record in 08:20:00 regardless of day)                     
08:30:00     No Autorizado      0210           10           1.7 (mean of every record in 08:30:00 regardless of day
```

i apologize for my english and i hope someone can help me

Comment: A nested groupby is highly inefficient. Can you go a little more in depth as to how you want each column aggregated?

Comment: Well, What o need to see is the mean of the amount of every possible transaction in 10 minutes so it would be like this:. Mean of every transaction between 08:20 and 08:30 (plus any other hour)  = sum(amount of transactions in that range of time)/distinct count(days)

Comment: To clarify something above, is the mean of the sum of every possible transactions in 10 min